# Android: Positioning buttons when turned from portrait to landscape

Tags: android, layout, button, position

I have a menu-activity, in which I have several positioned buttons. It fits my phone screen perfectly when in portrait mode, but in landscape mode it's destroyed. I know that when I have fixed positioning this will be the result. Can anyone tell me how to position my buttons so my activity keeps its form also in landscape mode? Thank you.

Here is my xml file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >


<Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/bezpecnost_over"
     android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
     android:layout_marginTop="50dp"


      />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/kurenie_over"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"

     />

  <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/osvetlenie_over"
    android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp" 
    android:onClick="obrOsv"    />


<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@drawable/pohodlie_over"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

> It fits my phone screen perfectly when in portrait mode, but in
>   landscape mode it's destroyed.

This is expected for relative-based layouts. What developers usually do in this scenario:

- Make a folder under res called `layout-land`
- Make an xml with the *same* name as the layout in portrait mode (contained in `res/layout`)
- Position for landscape mode.

Since the xml file name is the same, when it is time for the activity to set the content view

```
setContentView (R.layout.my_layout);
```

The `my_layout.xml` file from the `layout-land` folder will be used instead.

Also read [*Layouts*](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) & [*Supporting Multiple Screens*](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) from the Android docs, they both have useful information with the latter talking about the different qualifiers (such as `layout-land`).

Comment: That's the way i was taught on how to do it too.  unless you want to scale their position based on the screen size? Don't think that would work though or would be too much work for the same solution.

Comment: @MartinNemeth [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html) link should go a bit more in depth about how to support multiple screen *sizes*. It talks about using match_parent to your advantage as well as making use of the qualifiers. However keep in mind the simpler your layout is, the easier it is to adapt for multiple screens.

Comment: @MartinNemeth If my answer has solved your issue, then you should [accept it as the best answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). If you need more clarification, feel free to ask. Or, if you solved the problem in a different way, answer your own question detailing how you did.

Answer (score 0):

So you're using a relative layout to space out buttons horizontally by using increasing amounts of margin?  That's totally not understanding how layouts work.  Start by replacing the RelativeLayout with a LinearLayout with orientation set to horizontal, and get rid of all the margins-  margins should just be a few pixels between elements.  I'd suggest you read the Android tutorials on how layouts work.