# How to save and load state of an application during change of screen orientation in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been trying to make an application, and since I am new to android development I am stuck with this small problem. The application which when opened shows this layout as the first page.[image: First page]

Then after choosing the content from the list view a fragment transaction occurs and this page is opened.
[image: Description of the selected list view item]

I have used fragments because I have used drawer layout and tabbed layout using action bar sherlock theme.

The problem I am facing is after the screen is rotated the previous fragment is loaded, i.e. it takes me back to the list view page from the information page.
[image: Taken back to previous fragment]

I have read that we have to save and load the state of the application but as I am new to this I don't know how to implement it. Please help!!!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17341295/retaining-data-on-screen-orientation-change

Comment: so to save the list view whose content is obtained from the database I will have to save the instance of the list view and then load it in the onCreate method

Comment: Yes. That is what the answer states. Saving all views and then retrieving them later.

Comment: Do we always have to create separate layouts for the landscape and portrait orientations

Comment: Yes well usually since you want the views aligned according to the orientation. If you want to save time, you could just lock the orientation.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try this out :)
Is there any special naming convention that i have to follow while creating layouts for the landscape mode?

Comment: This will help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124046/how-do-i-specify-different-layouts-for-portrait-and-landscape-orientations

Comment: Suppose I have used relative layout in my portrait file and I copied the same file to layout-land, will the device automatically recognize the layout and fit it according to the size of screen or will I have to change layout specifications in the XML file of landscape orientation

Comment: It actually doesn't work that way. Read about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14842847/android-positioning-buttons-when-turned-from-portrait-to-landscape. Sorry for posting links. Explanations would take a long time :P

Comment: @AndyFaizan  
No problem :) Actually while developing another application I was stuck with a similar problem in which after the change of screen orientation the buttons would look distorted i.e one button would overlap another button. In that application too I was using relative layout and a scroll view. But the scroll view wasn't working. I tried both the ways scroll view inside relative layout and relative layout inside scroll view. Is there any method which can solve this problem

Comment: You'll have to put up a question with code for that (but do your research before posting) :)